# @Select condition with Enum type does not work in @AlternateMessage annotation

Tags: gwt, resources, internationalization

Inherit com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N in your module.

Create a simple Messages interface:

```
public interface Languages extends Messages {
    enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE;
    }
    @AlternateMessage({ 
        "MALE", "{0} gave you his credits.", 
        "FEMALE", "{0} gave you her credits." 
    })
    @DefaultMessage("{0} gave you their credits.")
    String gaveCredits(String name, @Select Gender gender);
}
```

Add system out to EntryPoint onModuleLoad:

```
Languages lang = GWT.create(Languages.class);
System.out.println(lang.gaveCredits("Helmut", Gender.MALE));
```

Actual result:

```
"Helmut gave you their credits."
```

Expected result:

```
"Helmut gave you his credits."
```

Did I get something wrong? Why wouldn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should have worked, but unfortunately there was a bug (fixed last week) that would only process `@Select` when there's also a `@PluralCount` in the method: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10226